# How to call an Express function from my Angular view ( MEAN.js )

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack, meanjs

I have a MEAN.js application, and I'm trying to figure out how I would call a function in my express application from my Angular view. I was thinking I could do it with web sockets perhaps. I'm new to Angular so I'm not sure if there is an "Angular" way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a restful endpoint for your function. Create a route in express to access that function. Now requests can be made from the front end code to this route. Now, since you are using Angular in the front end, the common way to call the restful endpoint is through $http or $resource service.